# How do I disable camera autofocus on the Galaxy S5?

Tags: camera, video

I'm trying to take video with my camera on my Galaxy S5, but the shots are almost always out of focus, or the autofocus will kick in randomly and leave the shot blurred.

I have tried the stock camera app and Open Camera, both have this issue.

The phone is useless to me unless I can resolve this issue, every video has a problem with blurring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for telling you the truth , but you cant really disable autofocus from the stock camera app...

Comment: Can you disable it in some other way?

Comment: No worries. I'm furious with the phone company for selling me a terrible phone, but it's not android's fault.